# Can one do the equivalent of nesting the CSS dot operator?

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have a CSS stylesheet as follows:

```
.commandsTable {
    color: whitesmoke;
    background-color: black;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}

.commandsTable td {
    background-color: #039be5;
}

.commandsTable tr:hover {
    background-color: black;
}
```

As one can see, '.commands table' is repeated twice to style the td and tr elements respecitvely.

So...

Is there a way of nesting dot (.) operators in CSS in order to prevent repetitive code entry?

Comment: I don't see a problem? css rule is a match and fail game, the soon a match fails the soon it move to the next one.

Comment: @DanielH you're used to css :) there is an awful lot of repeated code in that language

Comment: @Dale ~.~ All I know is that for each element it will go to the style sheet and go through all css rule to find a match, right to left, as soon as it fails it move to the next. if you be specific I don't see a repeat styling? If you have a ref link about this please post, I want to learn more

Comment: well just look how many times '.commandsTable' is written :)... repeated code.. not repeated style :)

Comment: not in native CSS but you can use preprocessors like scss or less.

Comment: @Dale Oh ok, I thought we are talking about efficiency and performance. Yes, go SASS

Comment: Thanks guys and @Dale for sticking up for me 

Comment: SASS is amazing I have to say!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that only with a preprocessor like [sass](http://sass-lang.com/)

In pure css you can not nest elements

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link that would perfectly suit your requirement:http://tabatkins.github.io/specs/css-nesting/

While you can go for SASS, there is another option which is `cssnext` and you should definitely check it out.

Here's a link for it:http://cssnext.io/features/

Comment: Yes definitely give it a try. Will make your life tons easier.